# PHP PDO Fetching Same Results Multiple Times

Tags: php, pdo

For some reason when I try to fetch data from my database it returns my data multiple times.

```
$base = "mysql:host=" . $config["database"]["host"] . ";port=" . $config["database"]["port"]  . ";dbname=" . $config["database"]["name"];
$conn = new PDO($base, $config["database"]["user"], $config["database"]["pass"]);

$query = $conn->query("SELECT setting, value FROM main");

if(!$query->rowCount()){
    echo "An error occured while trying to load some important information. Please check your database credentials and data and try again.";
}
else{
    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP);

    var_dump($result);
}
```

For example assume I have the following data in my table:

```
setting  |  value
------------------
one      |  1
------------------
two      |  2
------------------
```

Calling the function var_dump() will print out:

```
array(2) {
    ["one"]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> string(56) "1"
  }
  ["two"]=> array(1) {
      [0]=> string(24) "2"
  }
}
array(2) {
    ["one"]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> string(56) "1"
  }
  ["two"]=> array(1) {
      [0]=> string(24) "2"
  }
}
array(2) {
    ["one"]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> string(56) "1"
  }
  ["two"]=> array(1) {
      [0]=> string(24) "2"
  }
}
array(2) {
    ["one"]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> string(56) "1"
  }
  ["two"]=> array(1) {
      [0]=> string(24) "2"
  }
}
```

Does anybody have any idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: That's odd. Only because lengths of "1" and "2" are not 56 and 24 respectively. But it looks like this piece of code is called multiple times in its entirity. That output is not the output of a single call to `var_dump`. You can verify by echoing a constant value before and/or after the var_dump.

Comment: Fetchall gives you the entire set in one swoop. Are you perhaps iterating through each row and running a vardump or otherwise thinking that you are doing it one row at a time?

Comment: Is there some other loop outside this code sample that you are not showing us?

Comment: By the way, if you are really trying to get unique values and have row grouping, it is probably better practice to actually do this in your SQL query rather then in PDO, unless you had some weird case where you didn't want to build indexes in MySQL.  This would be much better performance-wise if your table is going to grow large.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `var_dump` is executed multiple times.

Something calls it more than once.

I think it is not the code that is executed.

As

```
strlen('1') !== 56
```

Comment: `strlen('1') !== 56 ` sure, i think he hidden those data (content replaced by "1" and "2") for confidenciality reasons :-)